# Spring Resource Import

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

We are using spring (beans, context, core, expressions, webmvc (all 4.1.4) ws-core, ws-security, xml ( all 2.2.0)) for a long time. now we have made a switch from IBM WAS Full Profile to IBM WAS Liberty Profile.
And now the application is working with java1.6 instead java1.4. everything works fine except the resource loading. the problem are the import resource commands.
i have three imports in my ws-service.xml, one below the other. but only the lowermost import is working. if i swap the import commands i have the same result: only the lowermost is working.

```
<import resource="classpath*:mapping1.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:mapping2.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:mapping3.xml"/>
```

Only mapping3.xml is working

```
<import resource="classpath*:mapping3.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:mapping1.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:mapping2.xml"/>
```

Only mapping2.xml is working

What can i do?

Comment: Would you post the full path of these mapping XML files?

Comment: Hello Nikolas, the full path of these xml - files is d:\IBM_Liberty\LibertyProfilesForRAD\wlp-webProfile7-16.0.0.2\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\config\.    Greetings, Paul